# Set MenuItem click event to call logout function

Tags: c#, asp.net, menuitem, logout

I have a menu item "Login" that navigates to the login page.  When a user is logged in, I have the text for that menu item changing to "Logout".  When clicked, I want it to go back to clear the session, go to the login page, and for the text to change back to "Login".  And this works...kinda.  The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to call a function when clicking on a menu item, so when the user clicks "Logout" the login page loads and the session is cleared when the page loads, but since it's not cleared before the page loads, it still appears that there is a session (username still appears, and menu item text isn't changed).  How can I set it so that the session is cleared in "Logout" is clicked instead of when the login page loads?

Here's my menu code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LeftSideMenu.ascx.cs"   Inherits="EVMAnywhereWeb.Controls.LeftSideMenu" %>

<div id="leftSideMenu">
<asp:menu ID="menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Vertical" RenderingMode="List">
<StaticMenuItemStyle VerticalPadding="5" />
<DynamicMenuItemStyle VerticalPadding="5" />
<Items>
    <asp:menuitem navigateurl="~/Login.aspx" Text="Login" Value="Login"></asp:menuitem>
    <asp:menuitem navigateurl="~/Register.aspx" Text="Register" Value="Register"></asp:menuitem>
    <asp:menuitem navigateurl="~/Projects.aspx" Text="Projects" Value="Projects"></asp:menuitem>
    <asp:menuitem navigateurl="~/Dictionary.aspx" Text="Dictionary" Value="Dictionary"></asp:menuitem>
 </Items>   
</asp:menu>
</div>
```

Here's the code I use to change the text (in the code-behind):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["SessionUserName"] != null)
        {
            menu1.Items[0].Text = "Logout";
            menu1.Items[1].Text = "My Account";

        }
    }
```

And in the login page code-behind, I have this to clear the session:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["SessionUserName"] != null)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your code to clear the session in OnInit instead of Page_Load.

Comment: Unless I'm doing this wrong (which is likely) OnInit isn't working for me. 
`public new void OnInit(EventArgs e)

        {
            if (Session["SessionUserName"] != null)
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            }
        }`
I tried to use override instead of new, but that erred because I had nothing to override.  OnInit simply doesn't appear to be getting called at all.

Comment: OnInit gets always called. I think you need to make the method protected.

Example:

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) { ... }

Comment: Ok.  So that worked...mostly.  I'm having the same problem though, and I may not be able to change that.  The session is getting cleared, but the text for the menu item is not changing back to "Login".  I probably need to tell it to change back, but as the text is changed in the code behind for the menu control, I don't think I'm going to be able to change it.  Now, after I log out and the session is cleared, if I click on any of the menu items again, the text does change.  Just not when the user actually logs out.

Comment: I think I just found the missing part in your code :-)
You have to call Session.Clear additionally. Session.Abandon will only remove the cookie at the clients browser, afaik.